# Get thumbnailRenderer on all rest api responses?

Tags: api

I have a list with a column of images, I always want to get the thumbnailRenderer parameter in the sharepoint rest api response
sometimes i get.

my query is:

```
https://testttr.sharepoint.com/sites/testadmin/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Assets')/items?$select=Image

"Image": "{\"fileName\":\"12.jpg\",\"serverRelativeUrl\":\"/sites/testadmin/SiteAssets/Lists/bc4474ef-c463-4645-9561-ed3972135070/12.jpg\",\"id\":\"5768aaa4-9c33-4c5b-b17d-4bcf62fe2c4f\",\"serverUrl\":\"https://testttr.sharepoint.com\",\"thumbnailRenderer\":{\"spItemUrl\":\"https://testttr.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.1/drives/b!GtlpUBbcgkW_CHn3DwqYuAqWL0zDWtdEi1xPlBGSu7bE19ol3o3bk5f2f3R5hD0A5zU1Ze/items/1257365ALY702EDFGVJUFOM44LNGLC7KLZ5RP4LCP\",\"fileVersion\":2,\"sponsorToken\":\"L3NpdGUYQ4A2JH647443Rlc3RsYW5kaW5nL0xpc3RzL0Fzc2V0c3xJbWFLMF5x\"},\"type\":\"thumbnail\",\"fieldName\":\"Image\",\"fieldId\":\"0c537600-6d7f-42b2-930e-aedd2fHJ43E2GYH\"}"
```

***Note only on some occasions I get it but on others I do not. attach my answer**

```
"Image": "{\"type\":\"thumbnail\",\"fileName\":\"506-5062633_anthony-v-bova-una-persona-con-traje.png\",\"nativeFile\":{},\"fieldName\":\"Image\",\"serverUrl\":\"https://testttr.sharepoint.com\",\"fieldId\":\"0c535GE7600-6d7f-42b2-930e-aedd2f8U676PO7\",\"serverRelativeUrl\":\"/sites/testadmin/SiteAssets/Lists/bcHG7674ef-m463-445-9561-ed3974JGHF5f70/506-5062633_anthony-v-bova-una-persona-con-traje.png\",\"id\":\"49aG5Dd11-034d-4202155-9L9c-fdb254740927a\"}"
```

Comment: Are you uploading all images using SharePoint UI or programming or any automation, like [PowerApps](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/04/add-update-or-delete-images-in-sharepoint-microsoft-lists-using-power-apps/), [Power Automate](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/08/add-an-image-to-sharepoint-image-columns-using-power-automate/) or [PowerShell](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/13/add-update-image-columns-in-sharepoint-microsoft-lists-using-pnp-powershell/)?

Comment: I am uploading the images in the sharepoint list using the default form of sharepoint online @GaneshSanap